# If I use AWS DMS to migrate data from uncompressed Oracle DB to compressed DB, will I lose the compression on target DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle11g, database-migration, compression, dms

This is a data refresh activity.

My source DB is Oracle 11g. I am using AWS DMS to migrate the data from source to target DB Oracle 12c on which compression is applied. By doing so will I lost the compression on target DB? And if yes, is there any way to avoid that?

Please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Oracle.html#CHAP_Source.Oracle.Limitations)

**AWS Database Migration Service supports all compression methods supported by LogMiner.**

Answer (score 0):

We tested. Using DMS we did not lose the compression on target DB.